# APA Style citations and signal phrases using BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I would like to use BibLaTeX to generate the following in-text APA citation:

> According to Alice and Bob (2020) something happened. Also, something else happened (pp. 10–20).

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man]{apa6}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{books.bib}
\shorttitle{Title}
\begin{document}
According to \textcite{alice+bob} something happened. Also, something else happened.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This outputs the following:

> According to Alice and Bob (2020, pp. 10–20) something happened. Also, something else happened.

How can I instruct BibLaTeX to move "(pp. 10–20)" to the end of the second sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `\notecite` or `\pnotecite` citation commands. See p. 112 of the documentation.  I'm not sure whether this is proper APA style, however. I would probably prefer `\citeyear` instead to make the reference clearer without having to repeat the author.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
According to \textcite{baez/article} something happened. 
This also happened \pnotecite[424-426]{baez/article}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]